# Query string not bringing back results when URL parameter includes '20'

Tags: search-results, query-string

I have a query in a search result web part that is grabbing an event title from the URL parameter as follows:

Event1OWSTEXT={QueryString.eventTitle}

However, whenever there is a "20" in the event title, the query doesn't bring back any results. I assume it has something to do with the fact that spaces are encoded as %20 and it's confusing SharePoint, but I can't figure out a way to get around it. The business unit places the date in the title, and the year is 2020, so we will definitely be encountering this!

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try putting single quote marks around the value in the query string, for example `Event1OWSTEXT='myqueryvalue'`

Comment: @Wilman I was going to post that as an answer. Please do.

Comment: Thanks, @willman and Matthew. I tried this but wasn't successful. In my case, where would you recommend placing the single quotes? I tried both inside and outside the curly brackets, but I'm curious what you think would work.

Comment: When you are passing query values via URL, you don't use the curly brackets.

Comment: Even in KQL, @willman? I tried removing the curly brackets, and even my previously working SRWPs stopped returning results.